# AMF генерация

Tags: c++

Чем генерить amf формат? Есть готовое решение для c++ на пару десятков строк кода?

Comment: Речь про [этот AMF][1]?

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMF_(%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: Да. Парсер пришлось написать. Думаю надо выложить код, потому как даже на википедии нет ссылки на вариант на с++.